# SimpleXML data missing

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I have a XML which I parse with php simpleXML.

The XML:

```
<GetOneGetAll DateTimeSystem="28-06-2011 17:19:29" RetCode="200" RetVal="1" RetMsg="User ok.">
    <User Id="bc5cb4cf-19a6-4504-8e1a-f72dd97bcc66" ReferedConfirmedUsers="0" TotalRecomendations="0" DistinctRecomendations="0">
        <Name>Name</Name>
        <Surname>Surname</Surname>
        <Gender>F</Gender>
        <Email>email@email.com</Email>
        <RefererCode>59286904</RefererCode>
        <CustomPhotoMessage HasCustomPhoto="0" HasCustomMessage="0"/>   
        <ReferedConfirmedUsersList/>
    </User>
</GetOneGetAll>
```

When I print_r the var using simpleXML I get:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [DateTimeSystem] => 28-06-2011 17:22:52
            [RetCode] => 200
            [RetVal] => 1
            [RetMsg] => Login ok.
        )

    [User] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [Id] => bc5cb4cf-19a6-4504-8e1a-f72dd97bcc66
                    [ReferedConfirmedUsers] => 0
                    [TotalRecomendations] => 0
                    [DistinctRecomendations] => 0
                )

            [Name] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                )

            [Surname] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                )

            [Gender] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                )

            [Email] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                )

            [RefererCode] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                )

            [CustomPhotoMessage] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [HasCustomPhoto] => 0
                            [HasCustomMessage] => 0
                        )

                )

            [ReferedConfirmedUsersList] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                )
        )
)
```

Where is the data of Surname, Name, Email, Gender, etc.?

Comment: It loads fine for me.  Are you displaying this through a web page, or CLI?  Can you access the data and just not print_r it, or is the data not there through $xml_obj->User->Surname either?

Comment: Yes, it seems it's there, ican access it ... but doesn't show on the print_r.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a guess, but if you have [xdebug](http://xdebug.org/) installed, then the default recursion level of `var_dump` output is 3. This setting is [xdebug.var_display_max_depth](http://xdebug.org/docs/display)
You are using `print_r`, but some similar recursive limit could be being reached.